# Time Interval Presentation library for many languages

Tags: objective-c, localization

Does anybody know good Time Interval Presentation library for presenting date as
`N {days/weeks/etc} {ago/from date/from now/etc}`?

I found only [this formatter kit](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit).

But it is not good enough in localization for many languages. (for example, **Slavic languages**)

Thanks!

Comment: Why not write your own? A collection of strings files should be able to do what you want, and determining how long an interval is isnt too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty good library; I've looked for similar before and not found much better.

And it's open source -- if you (or whoever is helping you localize the rest of your app for Slavic languages) can provide the appropriate strings, you can integrate them with the library and share them for the benefit of others using the library.

If the problem is that it's not flexible enough to support all the localized strings needed for Slavic languages (i.e. extra cases, declensions, etc.), open source can help you there, too. Perhaps you can adapt the library to handle this, or get in touch with @mattt and/or other users of the library for help with such adaptation.

Comment: good advise, thanks! i do the same (write my own solution), but i don't want to invent wheel